# Powershell Script | Looking for matches from the first two octets

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

I have a script that gets the active IP address from the computer it's running on. If the first two octets contains that number, it will output "I'm in PH".

So if an address is 10.4.20.52,  I need to create a decision where if the IPAddress -contains" "10.4" write "I'm in PH"  Else "Im not in PH".

I tried to use -Like -iLike and -contains and none of them seem to be working.

```
$NICIndex = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_IP4RouteTable |
    Where-Object { $_.Destination -eq "0.0.0.0"-and $_.Mask -eq "0.0.0.0" } |
    Sort-Object Metric1 |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex
$AdapterConfig = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter |
    Where-Object { $_.InterfaceIndex -eq $NICIndex } |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
$ipconfig = (Get-First $AdapterConfig.IPAddress);


$ipconfig


if ($ipconfig -contains '10.4.')
{
  Write-host "I'm in PH"  
}
else
{
  Write-host "I'm not in PH"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I just figured it out, I used -Match and it worked.  

never mind I guess

Comment: `-contains` is used to see if an array contains an element. It doesn't match a substring.

Comment: @TheInfamousOne If you've found the answer to your own question, post it as an answer so others with the same question can see the answer clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($ipconfig -like '10.4.*')  # or if ($ipconfig -match '^10\.4\.')
{
  Write-host "I'm in PH"  
}
else
{
  Write-host "I'm not in PH"
}
```